# Error Handler Doesn't Catch res.download Request Abortion

Tags: node.js, express

I have a Express (`5.0.0-beta.1`) server set up with a minimal error handler.

Normally when I encounter an error in my application, I throw it for it to be caught by the error handler. But I've discovered that an error thrown in the callback function of `res.download()` evades the error handler.

If I manually invoke the error handler using `next(err)`, the error is caught. What is the reason that a thrown error evades the error handler in only this exact instance?

##### server.js

```js
...
app.use(api);
app.use((error, req, res, _next) => res.sendStatus(500));
...
app.listen(listenPort, () => {
  console.log(`\n--------------listening on: ${listenPort}-----------------\n`);
});
```

##### api.js

```js
router.get('/api/downloadFile', async (req, res, next) => {
  res.download('./mock.ts', 'myFile', (err) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err; //  not caught by error handler and crashes server
      // next(err)  is caught by error handler
    }
  });
});
```

The [documentation on error handling](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download) in the `res.download()` callback method reminds us:

> "the response may be partially-sent, so check res.headersSent"

My guess is that this is a clue in the right direction, but I don't really understand why that would cause the difference in behavior between `throw err` and `next(err)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [error-handling](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)

> Errors that occur in synchronous code inside route handlers and middleware require no extra work. If synchronous code throws an error, then Express will catch and process it. For example:

```js
app.get('/', function testController(req, res) {
  throw new Error('BROKEN') // Express will catch this on its own.
})
```

When a request comes, it will call [`Layer.prototype.handleRequest`](https://github.com/pillarjs/router/blob/v2.0.0-beta.1/lib/layer.js#L91) method underly:

```js
Layer.prototype.handleRequest = function handleRequest (req, res, next) {
  var fn = this.handle

  if (fn.length > 3) {
    // not a standard request handler
    return next()
  }

  try {
    // invoke function
    var ret = fn(req, res, next)

    // wait for returned promise
    if (isPromise(ret)) {
      ret.then(null, function (error) {
        next(error || new Error('Rejected promise'))
      })
    }
  } catch (err) {
    next(err)
  }
}
```

The value of `this.handle` property will be the `testController` function. As you can see, it uses `try...catch` statement internally to handle the error thrown by `testController`. But `try...catch` can not catch the error thrown by asynchronous code like below, so you must pass the error to `next()` function.

> For errors returned from asynchronous functions invoked by route handlers and middleware, you must pass them to the `next()` function, where Express will catch and process them

```js
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  // try...catch does not work with the below asynchronous code.
  fs.readFile('/file-does-not-exist', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      next(err) // Pass errors to Express.
    } else {
      res.send(data)
    }
  })
})
```

BTW, [`express` v5.0.0-beta.1](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/v5.0.0-beta.1/package.json#L54) uses [router v2.0.0-beta.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/router) package instead of [lib/router](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/4.18.2/lib/router/index.js) module.